# awk script to read input file with different number of fields in each line

Tags: awk

Input file has different number of fields in each line.

Is there any way to get the expected output with awk?

`awk -F',' '{print "echo "$1; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print "command1 "$i " command2"}' test.txt`

**test.txt**

```
"abc",4,21,22,25
"standard",1 
"test",4,5,10,11,12
```

**Output:**

```
echo "abc"
command1 4 command2
command1 21 command2
command1 22 command2
command1 25 command2
echo "standard"
command1 1 command2
echo "test"
command1 4 command2
command1 5 command2
command1 10 command2
command1 11 command2
command1 12 command2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
echo "abc" command1 4 command2
echo "abc" command1 21 command2
echo "abc" command1 22 command2
echo "abc" command1 25 command2
echo "standard" command1 1 command2
echo "test" command1 4 command2
echo "test" command1 5 command2
echo "test" command1 10 command2
echo "test" command1 11 command2
echo "test" command1 12 command2
```

Comment: Your input is CSV so - can the first field include commas, e.g.`"hello, world",3,7,21`? How about escaped quotes, e.g. `"hello, \"world\"",3,7,21` or `"hello, ""world""",3,7,21`? How about newlines?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print "echo", $1, "command1", $i, "command2"}'
```

Eg:

```
$ cat file
"abc",4,21,22,25
"standard",1
"test",4,5,10,11,12

$ awk -F, '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print "echo", $1, "command1", $i, "command2"}' file
echo "abc" command1 4 command2
echo "abc" command1 21 command2
echo "abc" command1 22 command2
echo "abc" command1 25 command2
echo "standard" command1 1  command2
echo "test" command1 4 command2
echo "test" command1 5 command2
echo "test" command1 10 command2
echo "test" command1 11 command2
echo "test" command1 12 command2
```

Default `OFS` is a space, so I just use commas to separate different things which needed to print.

For fun, GNU `sed` solution:

```
sed -r '/,/!d;/,/{s/([^,]*),([^,]*)/"echo" \1 "command1" \2 "command2"\n\1/; P; D;}'
```

Another noloop `awk` approach similar to [RavinderSingh13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54301955/5403468), but concise:

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/,/,"\necho " $1 " command1 ");sub(/[^\n]*\n/,"");gsub(/\n|$/," command2\n");printf $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A diferent approach without using loops here.

```
awk -F, '
/^\"/ && prev{
  print prev
  prev=""
}
{
  gsub(/,/,"\necho "  $1  " command1 ")
}
{
  gsub(/$/," command2")
  prev=$0
  sub(/.*\"\n/,"",prev)
  gsub(/\n/," command2\n",prev)
}
END{
  if(prev){
    print prev
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
echo "abc" command1 4 command2
echo "abc" command1 21 command2
echo "abc" command1 22 command2
echo "abc" command1 25 command2
echo "standard" command1 1  command2
echo "test" command1 4 command2
echo "test" command1 5 command2
echo "test" command1 10 command2
echo "test" command1 11 command2
echo "test" command1 12 command2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the echo statement inside the for loop

```
$ awk -F',' '{for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print "echo "$1  " command1 "$i " command2"}' test.txt
echo "abc" command1 4 command2
echo "abc" command1 21 command2
echo "abc" command1 22 command2
echo "abc" command1 25 command2
echo "standard" command1 1  command2
echo "test" command1 4 command2
echo "test" command1 5 command2
echo "test" command1 10 command2
echo "test" command1 11 command2
echo "test" command1 12 command2

$
```